# set value to None zipping two lists into dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

How can i set a value to None zipping two lists if the value list is out of range, say:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = ['a','b','c']
dict(zip(a,b))
```

So the output will be `{1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}`, but i needthis `{1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:None, 5:None}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
b = ['a','b','c'] + [None]*(len(a)-len(b))
```

Or doing this when constructing dict:

```
dict(zip(a,b +[None]*(len(a)-len(b))))
```

Comment: Convoluted, use izip_longest.

Comment: i thought of this solution, i like it

Answer (score 6):

The `itertools` module has you covered.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest

> itertools.izip_longest(*iterables[, fillvalue])
>
> Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.
>   If the iterables are of uneven length, missing values are filled-in
>   with fillvalue. Iteration continues until the longest iterable is
>   exhausted.

Comment: Our keys getting None when we have len(key_list) < len(value_list) - we'd liek to ignore assignment in this case